# Assistance please with a cors error on redirect

Tags: javascript, cors

I need your assistance please because I have a CORS error when attempting to upload from a drag and drop image(s) uploader. It errors out on CORS issues. The drag and drop works which means it seems like the actual upload is the only failure.

I need to know what workaround or other solution there might be.

The error message in console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://domain1.com/upload' from origin 'https://domain2.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

My dashboard (therefore this script), is on one domain (domain1.com) and the file(s) is/are to be uploaded to domain2.com/upload, that being the domain on which I store all the static files.

[edit]afterthought: Is the link correct? Should it be a link to a script or to the image dir?[/edit]

Heres the javascript

```
function uploadFile(file, i) {    
//var url = 'https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/joezimim007/image/upload'
var url = "domain2.com/upload"
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
var formData = new FormData()
xhr.open('POST', url, true)
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')

// Update progress (can be used to show progress indicator)
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
updateProgress(i, (e.loaded * 100.0 / e.total) || 100)
})

xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    updateProgress(i, 100) // <- Add this
    //console.log('xhr ready state   :  ' + xhr.readyState  );
  }
  else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
    // Error. Inform the user
    //console.log('upload error ' );
    //console.log( 'xhr ready state  :  '  +  xhr.readyState); 

  }
})

formData.append('upload_preset', 'ujpu6gyk')
formData.append('file', file)
xhr.send(formData) 
}
```

Comment: The error message seems clear enough. The API is returning a redirect for the preflight request. You need to fix the API.

Comment: Your custom header forces a preflight, The API likely does not support OPTIONS

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42172732/441757. The solution may be as simple as just adding a `/` trailing slash to the request URL; for example, `https://domain1.com/upload/` rather than `https://domain1.com/upload`. Or otherwise, look at the Location header of the response to the preflight, and use the URL in that Location header as the request URL in your frontend code.

Answer (score -1):

Add the "proxy" property (found at the bottom here) to package.json:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:<PORT-GOES-HERE>"
```

Now, instead of making HTTP requests like this:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:8080/example")
```

You should write them like this:

```
axios.get("/example")
```

or

Also you can install CORS plugins for Chrome ("Moesif COR"S or "Allow CORS") or also you can add your front-end domain to allow hosts on your back-end.

Comment: What package.json? I can't see anything in the question which suggests the OP is using any kind of framework that would involve them using Node.js let alone one which pays attention to a `proxy` directive.

Comment: "Also you can install CORS plugins for Chrome" — They are notoriously bad at supporting preflight requests so won't work here. It is also unreasonable to expect everybody visiting a website to install a plugin that turns off a security feature of their browser.