# CORS preflight request error: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request

Tags: laravel, axios, cors

I have [Vue3 application](https://github.com/camohub/tatrytec-vue-admin/blob/master/src/components/articles/ArticlesDataTable.vue) with Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set up according [documentation](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors#echodie)
for the package which sends this headers. Every common GET requests have this headers but if the form request send POST request then Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is not included in the response. It throws an error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://tatrytec.eu/api/article/store/'
> from origin 'https://vue.tatrytec.eu' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
> Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Here is my config/cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

and this is in Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
    \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
];
```

Here is the code of ArticlesController::store() method which throws an error: https://github.com/camohub/tatrytec.eu/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Api/ArticlesController.php#L63

Can somebody tell me please what should I set up in the server code to send required header ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: add header "Content-Type": "application/json"  and Accept  to axios call

Comment: Where? Also other requests works well and includes Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. This is the problem of form validation.

Comment: It looks like Laravel is returning a redirect instead of a json response (Maybe redirect()->back()->withErrors()). But that's just me guessing.. You should post your controller method here.

Comment: Here is the code of API ArticlesController::store() which throws an cors error https://github.com/camohub/tatrytec.eu/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Api/ArticlesController.php#L63

Comment: I update the question. The CORS issue occurs on every POST requests not only on validation error.

Comment: Just browsed through your code at GitHub. You are using tokens to autheticate and make request from your frontend while ensuring frontend requests are stateful in your backend which expects your frontend using cookie-based authentication.

Comment: Dont understand. I am pretty sure API requests are stateless. Cause if authentication is statefull all requests behind the auth middleware should throw an error. And I dont see any cookies in the console.

Comment: The problem was in redirect caused by trailing slash in request url.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This CORS issue is caused by preflight request redirect which is caused by trailing slash at the end of the request url. It seems the server app try to redirect to canonical url without trailing slash. Many thanks to the author of the [answer about this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42172732/4179032).

Comment: Amazing. This saved me many more hours of messing around.

Comment: That extra forward slash `/` is the major problem, especially on a query string. For example, instead of `users/?s=johndoe` use `users?s=johndoe`.

Comment: saved me after 5 hours of debugging

Comment: even chat GPT could help me with this situation, I lost 6 hours of asking and decided to search, them and I found here the solution, thank you!

Comment: Could or could not?

Comment: I don't know how I never knew this, but just ran into this issue in Laravel 10.X and finally got it to work with this. Thanks