# enable cors in a nginx with reverse proxy to strawberry-graphql python app with asgi using daphne

Tags: python, nginx, cors, daphne, asgi

I have a website that has the following setup:

- the client is an angular 14 project
- the server is a python app with strawberry for graphql
- using nginx as web server
- using asgi python script to run the app using daphne

I'm having cors related errors when I try to access graphql from the angular app

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://URL/graphql' from origin 'https://URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

in the nginx server i have `listen 443 ssl http2;` set with certificates from lets encrypt

I created an upstream setup for the python project:

```
upstream myproj-server {
  server 127.0.0.1:8001;
  }
```

created a location backend:

```
 location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://myproj-server; # <--- THIS DOES NOT HAVE A TRAILING '/'
    #proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*";
    #proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    #proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    #proxy_set_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With';
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

and setup graphql location:

```
     location /graphql {
#           add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*" always;
#        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
#        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
#        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
    }
```

i commented out the CORS lines with `#` but i did try to enable them, to add cors at the `/graphql` location or at the proxy configured in the `backend`, both configurations did not change anything.

next, i have a `server.py` with the asgi application with the strawberry plugin for the graphql:

```
from strawberry.asgi import GraphQL

from app import schema

app = GraphQL(schema, graphiql=False)
```

and i start it with `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 server:app`

and here I tried to modify `server.py` to use the `Starlette` CORS middleware

```
from strawberry.asgi import GraphQL
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.applications import Starlette

from app import schema

middleware = [
    Middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_headers=["*"],)
]

graphql_app=GraphQL(schema, graphiql=True)

app = Starlette(middleware=middleware)
app.add_route("/graphql", graphql_app)
app.add_websocket_route("/graphql", graphql_app)
```

and also here the results are the same

I'm sure that the reverse proxy works properly because if i set `graphiql` to True and i browse `mydomain/graphql` it does open the graphql-playground.

so I tried anything i can think of and i'm pretty lots, so any ideas or any information regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168773/how-to-resolve-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-or-redirect-is-not-allowed-for/42172732#42172732

Answer (score -1):

I checked the network tab of my browser and I noticed that what the `OPTIONS` request (for the CORS preflight request) fails with error 301, which is redirect. and then I noticed that the graphql url is `mydomain.com/graphql` and not `www.mydomain.com/graphql` and I do redirect to www in my nginx configuration.

i disabled the headers in the nginx i prefer to control it outside of the nginx configuration.

the server.py configuration with starlette did the trick. of course now i'll make it more secured.