# Why Binance API raise CORS, how to handle it?

Tags: reactjs, cors, binance

Got this error from Binance:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Calling like this in a React app.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const { data } = await axios.get('https://binance.com/api/v3/klines', {
                headers: { crossDomain: true },
                params: {
                    symbol: 'ETHUSDT',
                    interval: '1h',
                    startTime: '1514764800000',
                },
            })
        fetchData()
    }, [])
```

From Postman it works, what is the problem?

Full error:

> bot:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=ETHUSDT&interval=1h&startTime=1514764800000' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

---

tried `withCredentials: true`, did not work

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
            const { data } = await axios.get('https://binance.com/api/v3/klines', {
                withCredentials: true,
                headers: {},
```

---

tried proxy:

```
const { data } = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api2/klines', {
```

and set rewrite `next.config.js`:

```
async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/api2/:path*',
                destination: `https://binance.com/api/v3/:path*`,
            },
        ]
    },
```

got this error:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Postman is not a browser so it works  .... seems some header is missing to satisfy the request

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168773/how-to-resolve-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-or-redirect-is-not-allowed-for) helps?

Comment: Not really, if I remove `crossDomain: true`, I got a `307 Internal Redirect` from Binance. Adding trailing slash also did not help, and use a reverse proxy also did not help.

Comment: Which header I need as extra?

Answer (score -2):

You can send a request throw the CORS proxy.
[List of proxies](https://gist.github.com/jimmywarting/ac1be6ea0297c16c477e17f8fbe51347).
Like this:

```
axios.get(<proxy url>/<my url>).
```

Or [create your own](https://dev.to/imiebogodson/fixing-the-cors-error-by-hosting-your-own-proxy-on-heroku-3lcb).

Comment: I tried, did not work, see above