# CORS preflights error when using redirect

Tags: express, rest, cors, middleware, cors-anywhere

I`m trying to realize redirecting to another page of my app (current location 'http://localhost:3000/create-item' redirect to 'http://localhost:3000/subscribe') after saving item to database on my express server using next code (client send POST message to endpoint with form data):

```
await item.save(); 
 res.writeHead(302, { Location: 'http://localhost:3000/subscribe' });
 res.end();
```

one more variant:

```
await item.save();
res.redirect('/subscribe');
```

In base file of my server index.js i use my custom CORS middleware:

```
//cors.middleware.js
function cors(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization',
  );
  next();
}
module.exports = cors;

//index.js
const corsMiddleware = require('./middleware/cors.middleware');
app.use(corsMiddleware);
```

I also tryed:

```
 npm i cors
    app.use(cors());
```

Nevertheless I recieve CORS error while redirecting. So, what I`m doing wrong? Maybe this is related to sending data with POST method (redirect inside GET endpoint working well without CORS erro)

Comment: Hey, Have you tried solutions mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168773/how-to-resolve-preflight-is-invalid-redirect-or-redirect-is-not-allowed-for

Comment: This might help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSExternalRedirectNotAllowed

Comment: I don't think CORS works correctly with redirects sadly. Our workaround was to emit a JSON response when we detect a browser. The JSON response has the 'redirect url' and our frontend client knows how to listen to it .